# How to press Alt F4 using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently working on a program and I want to press Alt f4 to close all the tabs. I can't use driver.close because I need to close 2 tabs and the command only close one.
I've look everywhere but I couldn't find something using python.

I've tried that but it's not working : `ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "w").perform()`

Comment: Once you close the active window, then you will need to switch to the other window and close it

Comment: @0m3r no i don't want to close 2 windows but 2 tabs in the same windows. But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this in your project:

```
import keyboard
```

and then once you are done with your task with selenium

```
keyboard.press('alt')
keyboard.press('f4')
keyboard.release('f4')
keyboard.release('alt')
```

this can help you close the browser once done

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with web driver itself by using quit(). quit() is a webdriver command which closes all open browser windows:

```
driver.quit()
```

Comment: No I can't use that because my program repeat the task a certain number of time. If I do that, it will stop the program.

Comment: He is asking on how to send two keys together not how to get quit the driver.